# Is the expression 学识渊博 usually used in a pejorative sense?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

For example, as a sarcastic remark in the sense of "pedantic" or "know-it-all"?

Comment: "Knowledgeable" comes to mind.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: This is usually a positive word.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's usually used as a commendatory term. But it can be also used in a pejorative sense (the rule is called `褒義貶用`).

PS: This is not used in a conversation, or it's an irony.

Comment: So 褒义贬用 means "a sarcastic compliment" or "to make a sarcastic compliment"? I might add that to CC-CEDICT.

Comment: @trideceth12 To use a commendatory term as a derogatory term. (um, sorry for my poor English)

Comment: @trideceth12 Yeah. That's right. But it's a grammatical concept, not a word.